# PhoneGap File Sharing and Editing of Files

Tags: cordova

We are currently in the design process for an iPad / Android app using PhoneGap.

What we need to know is whether we can edit files using the app, that are stored within the File Sharing folder of the app?

I know we can load them, but can we modify them and save them back to the File Sharing folder?

I know there is an API for writing files but Apple seem to always have funny ideas about what apps can and cannot do hence the question.

## edit

Ok in iTunes you can navigate to the Apps folder and you can then drag files to the application which the application can then see.

On an android, you can simply copy files over to the device and the tablet can then read the files.

Comment: which kind of files do you want to edit?

Comment: These will be json files.

Comment: and what do you mean by the File Sharing folder? to share with itunes? or other apps?

Comment: Then yes, you can edit that files, but you have to activate the itunes file sharing editing the info.plist, you have to check the UIFileSharingEnabled option. Using the window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail); you get the Documents directory, that is the shared folder

Comment: jcesar, write that up as an answer.  and thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then yes, you can edit that files, but you have to activate the itunes file sharing editing the info.plist, you have to check the UIFileSharingEnabled option. Using the window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail); you get the Documents directory, that is the shared folder

Comment: Can that option be set via `config.xml`?

Comment: as far as I know, that isn't possible, I'll check

Comment: It's possible if you use phonegap build platform, but it isn't possible on regular cordova projects. You have to do it manually from xcode or create a cordova plugin that just sets this value

Comment: That's what I thought... I modified the info.plist manually and it is all good ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to enable file sharing in iOS as an actual app and not mess with the info.plist file in xcode, you can modify your config.xml file to include something like this:

```
<gap:config-file platform="ios" parent="UIFileSharingEnabled" mode="replace">
  <true/>
</gap:config-file>
```

This is noted in the PhoneGap documentation, but I'll admit that it was really buried and a bit difficult to find.

http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/configuring_config_file_element.md.html#Config%20File%20Elements

Comment: Thanks I'll check it out

Answer (score 0):

Might be better to save your data to an SQLLite file or CouchDB http://couchdb.apache.org/ and then rewrite the file.

Comment: This looks great but we really need to cater for tablets that are not connected to either WiFi or the internet so everything needs to be local.